# Remove class of next div after 800ms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add class to next element after .color inside parent div, and then after 800 miliseconds I want that this class to be removed.

My code looks like this:

```
$(".color").click( function () { 
  $(this).next().addClass("class");
  setTimeout(function(){ $(this).next().removeClass("class"); }, 800); 
})
```

Adding class works fine, but I have issue with removing it. The problem is probably in scope of setTimeout() function, but i can't figure it out.

Maybe some short explanation could help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be resolved via the use of an arrow function for the handler of your call to `setTimeout()` as shown:

```
$(".color").click( function () {

    $(this).next().addClass("class");

    // Use arrow function to resolve the "access to context" problem
    setTimeout(() => { $(this).next().removeClass("class"); }, 800); 
})
```

The idea of `this` in arrow functions is slightly different to that of regular functions.

Unlike regular functions that, by default, have their own `this` instance, arrow functions instead inherit `this` from their calling context. That means the `this` of the arrow function above would be the same as the `this` of the `click()` function. In situations like yours, the use of arrow functions in this way can be quite useful, allowing direct and convenient access to the calling context from a nested function (compared to what is shown below).

Alternatively, if your target browser doesn't support arrow functions, you can resolve this issue by the following method:

```
$(".color").click( function () {

    var colorNext = $(this).next();        
    colorNext.addClass("class");

    setTimeout(function () { colorNext.removeClass("class"); }, 800); 
})
```

Comment: Yes, I got it and works great. Thank you for your time!